# Problems adding SSL redirect to htaccess file on host

Tags: .htaccess, ssl

I have this for my htaccess

```
RewriteRule ^(?:languages|Sources|upload|templates_c)\b.* index.php/$0 [L]
```

and when I add

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^/?(.*) https://%{SERVER_NAME}/$1 [R,L]
```

It does not work how do I add the ssl to the already made htaccess file.

Thanks

Comment: Try to move the rules for https redirect to the top of .htaccess, above other rules.

Comment: the site stops working ive tried every possible way changing it around moving it to the bottom nothing seems to work

Answer (score 0):

Do **not** use the `SERVER_NAME` variable. That is not always properly configured especially on shared hosting and is dependent on `UseCanonicalName` directive. Depending on the server it may be off or not configured among other things. Try this.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !^on
RewriteRule ^/?(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteRule ^(?:languages|Sources|upload|templates_c)\b.* index.php/$0 [L]
```

Comment: It still does the redirect and ive just spoken to the host they say its set up right. So this is the issue and only the issue.

Comment: could this have anything to do with it

Comment: if ($_SERVER['HTTPS'] == "on" && $settings['ssl_host'] != "yes") {
     $porthttp = "http://" . $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] .        $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
     header("Location: " . $porthttp);
     exit();
     }